# How to make radioButton as SQLite filter in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, radio-button, android-sqlite

This code filters the SQL query by 6 filters: name, weight, country, power and type. How to make RadioButton element as a separate filter? I have 6 RadioButton elements. Each element for one filter. Weight radioButton to filter by weight, Country radioButton to filter by country etc.

```
MySQLite
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class MySQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "phones";

    static final String TABLE_NAME = "emergency_service";
    static final String ID = "id";
    static final String NAME = "name";
    static final String PRICE = "price";
    static final String TYPE = "type";
    static final String POWER = "power";
    static final String WEIGHT = "weight";
    static final String COUNTRY = "country";

    static final String ASSETS_FILE_NAME = "vacuumcleaner.txt";
    static final String DATA_SEPARATOR = "|";

    private Context context;

    public MySQLite(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + NAME + " TEXT,"
                + PRICE + " TEXT,"
                + TYPE + " TEXT,"
                + POWER + " TEXT,"
                + WEIGHT + " TEXT,"
                + COUNTRY + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
        System.out.println(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
        loadDataFromAsset(context, ASSETS_FILE_NAME,  db);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        System.out.println("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void addData(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String price, String type, String power, String weight, String country) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NAME, name);
        values.put(PRICE, price);
        values.put(TYPE, type);
        values.put(POWER, power);
        values.put(WEIGHT, weight);
        values.put(COUNTRY, country);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }


    public void loadDataFromAsset(Context context, String fileName, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {

            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(fileName);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String strTrim = str.trim();
                if (!strTrim.equals("")) {
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(strTrim, DATA_SEPARATOR);
                    String name = st.nextToken().trim();
                    String price = st.nextToken().trim();
                    String type = st.nextToken().trim();
                    String power = st.nextToken().trim();
                    String weight = st.nextToken().trim();
                    String country = st.nextToken().trim();
                    addData(db, name, price, type, power, weight, country);
                }
            }


        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public String getData(String filter) {

        String selectQuery;

        if (filter.equals("")) {
            selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + NAME;
        } else {
            selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE (" + PRICE + " LIKE '%"  +
                    filter.toLowerCase() + "%'" +
                    " OR " + TYPE + " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'" + " OR " +  POWER + " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'"
                    + " OR " + WEIGHT + " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'" + " OR " + COUNTRY +
                    " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'" + " OR " + NAME + " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'" +") ORDER BY " + NAME;

        }

        System.out.println(selectQuery);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

        int num = 0;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int n = cursor.getColumnIndex(NAME);
                int t = cursor.getColumnIndex(PRICE);
                int k = cursor.getColumnIndex(TYPE);
                int s = cursor.getColumnIndex(POWER);
                int a = cursor.getColumnIndex(WEIGHT);
                int d = cursor.getColumnIndex(COUNTRY);
                String name = cursor.getString(n);
                String price = cursor.getString(t);
                String type = cursor.getString(k);
                String power = cursor.getString(s);
                String weight = cursor.getString(a);
                String country = cursor.getString(d);
                data.append(String.valueOf(++num) + ") " + name + ": " + price + ": "+ type + ": " + power + ": " + weight + ": " + country + ": " +"\n");
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return data.toString();
    }

}
```

This was SQLite class, here is MainActivity.java:

```
    MainActivity
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int LARGE_FONT = 16;
    private final int SMALL_FONT = 12;
    private int fontSize = SMALL_FONT;

    MySQLite db = new MySQLite(this);

    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton priceRadioButton;
    RadioButton powerRadioButton;
    RadioButton typeRadioButton;
    RadioButton weightRadioButton;
    RadioButton countryRadioButton;
    RadioButton nameRadioButton;


    static final String FILTER = "FILTER";
    String filter = "";

    SharedPreferences sPref;
    static final String CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "Config";
    static final String FONT_SIZE = "FontSize";

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putString(FILTER, filter);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setKeyListener(null);


        sPref = getSharedPreferences(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        fontSize = sPref.getInt(FONT_SIZE, SMALL_FONT);

        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize);
        textView.requestFocus();


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            editText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(FILTER));
        }

        textView.setText(R.string.Загрузка_данных);


        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        filter = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                        final String data = db.getData(filter);
                        textView.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                textView.setText(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();

            }

        });


        editText.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                editText.setText(filter);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        menu.findItem(R.id.large_font).setChecked(fontSize == LARGE_FONT);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.email) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{getString(R.string.myemail)});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.Добавьте_еще_номер));
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.Предлагаю_такой_номер));
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.Посылка_письма)));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.Нет_установленного_почтового_клиента, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.large_font) {
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            int size = item.isChecked() ? LARGE_FONT : SMALL_FONT;
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size);
            fontSize = size;
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.exit) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putInt(FONT_SIZE, fontSize);
        ed.apply();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest building the WHERE clause based upon the radio buttons and as some would suggest binding the search arguments to protect against SQL injection.

e.g. something along the lines of:-

```
public Cursor getData(String value, boolean price_rb, boolean type_rb, boolean power_rb, boolean weight_rb, boolean country_rb, boolean name_rb) {

    ArrayList<String> intermediateWhereArgs = new ArrayList<>();

    StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();
    if (value.length() < 1 || (!price_rb && !type_rb && !power_rb && !weight_rb && !country_rb && !name_rb)) {
        whereClause = null;
    } else {
        if(price_rb) {
            if (whereClause.length() > 0) {
                whereClause.append(" OR ");
            }
            whereClause.append(PRICE_COLUMN + " LIKE ?");
            intermediateWhereArgs.add(value);
        }
        if(type_rb) {
            if (whereClause.length() > 0) {
                whereClause.append(" OR ");
            }
            whereClause.append(TYPE_COLUMN + " LIKE ?");
            intermediateWhereArgs.add(value);
        }
        if(power_rb) {
            if (whereClause.length() > 0) {
                whereClause.append(" OR ");
            }
            whereClause.append(POWER_COLUMN + " LIKE ?");
            intermediateWhereArgs.add(value);
        }
        if(weight_rb) {
            if (whereClause.length() > 0) {
                whereClause.append(" OR ");
            }
            whereClause.append(WEIGHT_COLUMN + " LIKE ?");
            intermediateWhereArgs.add(value);
        }
        if(country_rb) {
            if (whereClause.length() > 0) {
                whereClause.append(" OR ");
            }
            whereClause.append(COUNTRY_COLUMN + " LIKE ?");
            intermediateWhereArgs.add(value);
        }
        if(name_rb) {
            if (whereClause.length() > 0) {
                whereClause.append(" OR ");
            }
            whereClause.append(NAME_COLUMN + " LIKE ?");
            intermediateWhereArgs.add(value);
        }
    }
    String[] whereArgs = null;
    if (intermediateWhereArgs.size() > 0) {
        whereArgs = new String[intermediateWhereArgs.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < intermediateWhereArgs.size(); i++) {
            whereArgs[i] = intermediateWhereArgs.get(i);
        }
    }
    String actualWhereClause = "";
    if (whereClause != null) {
        actualWhereClause = whereClause.toString();
    }
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME,null,actualWhereClause,whereArgs,null,null,NAME_COLUMN);
}
```

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want do perhaps consider this working example that utilises the above.

First **DatabaseHelper** (which includes the above) :-

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "the_table";
    public static final String ID_COLUMN = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String PRICE_COLUMN = "price";
    public static final String TYPE_COLUMN = "type";
    public static final String POWER_COLUMN = "power";
    public static final String WEIGHT_COLUMN = "weight";
    public static final String COUNTRY_COLUMN = "country";
    public static final String NAME_COLUMN = "name";
    public static final String TABLE_CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
            "," + PRICE_COLUMN + " TEXT" +
            "," + TYPE_COLUMN + " TEXT" +
            "," + POWER_COLUMN + " TEXT" +
            "," + WEIGHT_COLUMN + " TEXT" +
            "," + COUNTRY_COLUMN + " TEXT" +
            "," + NAME_COLUMN + " TEXT" +
            ")";

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    private static volatile DatabaseHelper instance;
    public static DatabaseHelper getDatabaseHelperInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance==null) {
            instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            instance.db = instance.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_SQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insert(Long id, String price, String type, String power, String weight, String country, String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if (id !=null) {
            cv.put(ID_COLUMN,id);
        }
        cv.put(PRICE_COLUMN,price);
        cv.put(TYPE_COLUMN,type);
        cv.put(POWER_COLUMN,power);
        cv.put(WEIGHT_COLUMN,weight);
        cv.put(COUNTRY_COLUMN,country);
        cv.put(NAME_COLUMN,name);
        long rv =  db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
        return rv;
    }

    public long insert(String price, String type, String power, String weight, String country, String name) {
        return insert(null,price,type,power,weight,country,name);
    }
    public Cursor getData(String value, boolean price_rb, boolean type_rb, boolean power_rb, boolean weight_rb, boolean country_rb, boolean name_rb) {

        ArrayList<String> intermediateWhereArgs = new ArrayList<>();

        StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();
        if (value.length() < 1 || (!price_rb && !type_rb && !power_rb && !weight_rb && !country_rb && !name_rb)) {
            whereClause = null;
        } else {
            if(price_rb) {
                if (whereClause.length() > 0) {
                    whereClause.append(" OR ");
                }
                whereClause.append(PRICE_COLUMN + " LIKE ?");
                intermediateWhereArgs.add(value);
            }
            if(type_rb) {
                if (whereClause.length() > 0) {
                    whereClause.append(" OR ");
                }
                whereClause.append(TYPE_COLUMN + " LIKE ?");
                intermediateWhereArgs.add(value);
            }
            if(power_rb) {
                if (whereClause.length() > 0) {
                    whereClause.append(" OR ");
                }
                whereClause.append(POWER_COLUMN + " LIKE ?");
                intermediateWhereArgs.add(value);
            }
            if(weight_rb) {
                if (whereClause.length() > 0) {
                    whereClause.append(" OR ");
                }
                whereClause.append(WEIGHT_COLUMN + " LIKE ?");
                intermediateWhereArgs.add(value);
            }
            if(country_rb) {
                if (whereClause.length() > 0) {
                    whereClause.append(" OR ");
                }
                whereClause.append(COUNTRY_COLUMN + " LIKE ?");
                intermediateWhereArgs.add(value);
            }
            if(name_rb) {
                if (whereClause.length() > 0) {
                    whereClause.append(" OR ");
                }
                whereClause.append(NAME_COLUMN + " LIKE ?");
                intermediateWhereArgs.add(value);
            }
        }
        String[] whereArgs = null;
        if (intermediateWhereArgs.size() > 0) {
            whereArgs = new String[intermediateWhereArgs.size()];
            for (int i=0; i < intermediateWhereArgs.size(); i++) {
                whereArgs[i] = intermediateWhereArgs.get(i);
            }
        }
        String actualWhereClause = "";
        if (whereClause != null) {
            actualWhereClause = whereClause.toString();
        }
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME,null,actualWhereClause,whereArgs,null,null,NAME_COLUMN);
    }
}
```

Some Activity code which utilises the above. The activity has a Radio Button group (so only 1 button can be selected).

The resultant data is listed in a ListView that uses a SimpleCursorAdapater. The data is refreshed every time a button is clicked, the data displayed dependant upon the text in the edit text. If empty, then ALL rows are displayed. Otherwise the respective button determines the filter.

- where this may or may differ is that only a single filter is aplied as only 1 button can be checked with a RadioGroup. If multiple radio buttons can be clicked then the filter will be on multiple columns (untested so may need tweaking accordingly).

**MainActivity** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText inputValue;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton priceRadioButton;
    RadioButton powerRadioButton;
    RadioButton typeRadioButton;
    RadioButton weightRadioButton;
    RadioButton countryRadioButton;
    RadioButton nameRadioButton;
    ListView listView;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
    Cursor csr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        inputValue = this.findViewById(R.id.value_edittext);
        radioGroup = this.findViewById(R.id.filter_radiogroup);
        priceRadioButton = this.findViewById(R.id.price_radiobutton);
        powerRadioButton = this.findViewById(R.id.power_radiobutton);
        typeRadioButton = this.findViewById(R.id.type_radiobutton);
        weightRadioButton = this.findViewById(R.id.weight_radiobutton);
        countryRadioButton = this.findViewById(R.id.country_radiobutton);
        nameRadioButton = this.findViewById(R.id.name_radiobutton);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                setupOrRefreshListView();
            }
        });
        listView = this.findViewById(R.id.list);
        databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getDatabaseHelperInstance(this);
        addSomeData();
        setupOrRefreshListView();
    }

    private void setupOrRefreshListView() {
        csr = databaseHelper.getData(
                inputValue.getText().toString(),
                priceRadioButton.isChecked(),
                typeRadioButton.isChecked(),
                powerRadioButton.isChecked(),
                weightRadioButton.isChecked(),
                countryRadioButton.isChecked(),
                nameRadioButton.isChecked()
        );
        if (sca==null) {
            sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    csr,
                    new String[]{
                            DatabaseHelper.ID_COLUMN,
                            DatabaseHelper.NAME_COLUMN
                    },
                    new int[]{
                            android.R.id.text1,
                            android.R.id.text2
                    },
                    0
            );
            listView.setAdapter(sca);
        } else {
            sca.swapCursor(csr);
        }
    }

    private void addSomeData() {
        databaseHelper.insert("10","type1","high","heavy","Australia","Fred");
        databaseHelper.insert("100","type2","medium","medium","France","Mary");
        databaseHelper.insert("1000","type3","normal","normal","England","Sue");
        databaseHelper.insert("10000","type4","low","light","Germany","Tom");
        databaseHelper.insert("100000","type5","none","very light","Spain","Jane");
    }
}
```

---

**Demo Run**

---

When run (only designed to run once, otherwise it will duplicate the data) the database is loaded with data (as per the `addSomeData` method):-

[image]

And the device shows :-

[image]

- for brevity just the id and the name are shown (rather than use a custom layout).
- i.e. all of the 5 rows added are displayed as expected.

If a button is clicked/checked then, as there is no text in the edit text, then the same data is displayed (but the button can be seen to be checked)

If text is added let's say 10 and the Price button (first) is checked (sorry for brevity/convenience labels not added) then:-

[image]

If 1000 then Sue etc.

If 1000% then Jane, Sue and Tom (1% or 10% would show all).

No data is shown if any of the other buttons are checked.

If %e% (or %E% as LIKE is not case dependant) is input then:-

- the Price button shows nothing.
- the Type button (second) shows all 5 ( as per typ**e**)
- The Power button (third) shows Jane and Mary (non**e** and m**e**dium)

  - e.g.
  - [image]

and so on.

**Additional re comment**

> I updated the code. Could you please check it and help me figuring this out.

Your issue is not with the filter SQL but that you are trying to update the **textView** from another thread and that isn't happening.

If you add a line to write the result of the filer to the log e.g.:-

```
                   textView.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println(data); //<<<<<<<<<< LINE ADDED FOR DEBUG
                            textView.setText(data);
                        }
                    });
```

The you will see that the log includes the expected result e.g. *(run using your MySQlite code)*

```
2022-11-30 06:47:13.971 13016-13056/a.a.so74607559javasqlitefilterbyradiobuttons I/System.out: SELECT  * FROM emergency_service WHERE (price LIKE '%f%' OR type LIKE '%f%' OR power LIKE '%f%' OR weight LIKE '%f%' OR country LIKE '%f%' OR name LIKE '%f%') ORDER BY name
2022-11-30 06:47:13.986 I/System.out: 1) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:13.986 I/System.out: 2) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:13.986 I/System.out: 3) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:13.986 I/System.out: 4) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:14.132 13016-13057/a.a.so74607559javasqlitefilterbyradiobuttons I/System.out: SELECT  * FROM emergency_service WHERE (price LIKE '%fr%' OR type LIKE '%fr%' OR power LIKE '%fr%' OR weight LIKE '%fr%' OR country LIKE '%fr%' OR name LIKE '%fr%') ORDER BY name
2022-11-30 06:47:14.155 I/System.out: 1) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:14.155 I/System.out: 2) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:14.155 I/System.out: 3) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:14.155 I/System.out: 4) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:18.367 13016-13058/a.a.so74607559javasqlitefilterbyradiobuttons I/System.out: SELECT  * FROM emergency_service WHERE (price LIKE '%fre%' OR type LIKE '%fre%' OR power LIKE '%fre%' OR weight LIKE '%fre%' OR country LIKE '%fre%' OR name LIKE '%fre%') ORDER BY name
2022-11-30 06:47:18.388 I/System.out: 1) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:18.388 I/System.out: 2) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:18.388 I/System.out: 3) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:18.388 I/System.out: 4) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:18.564 13016-13059/a.a.so74607559javasqlitefilterbyradiobuttons I/System.out: SELECT  * FROM emergency_service WHERE (price LIKE '%fred%' OR type LIKE '%fred%' OR power LIKE '%fred%' OR weight LIKE '%fred%' OR country LIKE '%fred%' OR name LIKE '%fred%') ORDER BY name
2022-11-30 06:47:18.583 I/System.out: 1) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:18.583 I/System.out: 2) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:18.583 I/System.out: 3) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia: 
2022-11-30 06:47:18.583 I/System.out: 4) fred: 100.00: type2: Medium: Medium: Australia:
```

- as can be seen for each character entered in the EditText results in the filter being applied so result after entering **f**, another result after entering **r** (so edit text is **fr**) and so on

**BUT** the extracted data is not reflected in the **textView** TextView.

Adding the method to the activity code:-

```
private void refreshTextView(String filteredDataResult) {
    textView.setText(filteredDataResult);
}
```

And then using:-

```
                    textView.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println(data); //<<<<<<<<<< REMOVE WHEN HAPPY WITH RESULT
                            //textView.setText(data); //<<<<<<<<<< COMMENTED OUT
                            refreshTextView(data); //<<<<<<<<<< LINE ADDED
                        }
                    });
```

The result being :-

When first run:-

[image]

- Hello World being the initial value as per the layout.

Enter **f** and :-

[image]

Change to **h** and :-

[image]

**x** and :-

[image]

- i.e. no data matches filter

clear the input and all rows are displayed:-

[image]

**However**

The radio buttons serve no purpose, see the original answer for how you could make use of the radio buttons to effect the filter.

Comment: I updated the code. Could you please check it and help me figuring this out.

Comment: I used your example above for the radiobutton, but as you can see from the code, it reads from a text file, and there is an error with columns.

Comment: Maybe I'm not inserting your example correctly into mine.

Comment: @DookiiPiking certainly your addData method works **IF** passed an SQLiteDatabase object (as I used your MySQLite code), additionally getData works (again used in the additional section of the answer). So it's either your loadDataFromAsset (suggest add some logging and examine the log, not by any chance a trapped exception).